# Adding a custom header to pickadate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datapicker

I use AMsul [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) and try to add a custom header by using jquery **.prepend**

It works fine, but when I use 2 datapickers on one page, to the first one my custom header is added twice, what make it looks ridiculous.

This is my js code:

```
    $.extend($.fn.pickadate.defaults, {
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,

    onRender: function () {
        var year = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'yyyy');
        var day = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'dd');
        var month = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'mmm');
        var labelday = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'dddd');
        console.log(year, day, month, labelday);

        $('.picker__header').prepend('<div class="picker__date-display"><div class="picker__weekday-display">' + labelday + '</div><div class="picker__month-display"><div>' + month + '</div></div><div class="picker__day-display"><div>' + day + '</div></div><div    class="picker__year-display"><div>' + year + '</div></div></div>');
    }
});
```

And this is the result when I use 2 datapickers on one page:
[image]

My html markup looks like that:

```
<!-- First datapicker-->
        <input placeholder="Selected date" type="text" id="input_from" class="form-control datepicker">

        <!--Second datapicker -->
        <input placeholder="Selected date" type="text" id="input_to" class="form-control datepicker">
```

And I initialize the picker via js:

```
// Datapicker initialization
        $('.datepicker').pickadate();
```

How can I make it to always add only one custom header to each datapicker, even if there is more then one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery prepend method will prepend what you give it to all elements matching the selector:

`$('.picker__header')`

This will prepend to both `.picker__header`s it can find every time it is fired. By putting it in the render callback, it is being called for every time a datepicker is rendered. Twice, therefore, because you have 2 datepickers.

The best thing would be to prepend in a callback that is only called once, or to increment a counter on the render callback. Something like:

```
var dateCounter = 0;

...

onRender: function () {
    dateCounter++;
    if (dateCounter === 2) {
        $('.picker__header').prepend(...
    }
}
```

But there are lots of ways to do this. Maybe there's something in the pickadate.js API that might be more elegant?

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I use your code and it works fine, but when I click to choose a date my custom header just disappear and do not appear again even if I re-click the picker. Is there a way to fix it? Btw, I tried to find something in amsul documentation, but after spending a few hours with no result I resigned.

Comment: It sounds like this is going to be a pain to do with JS alone. You should probably look at creating a custom theme: 

https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js

You can download the full, uncompressed library and add your own theme css to the folder.

Comment: But I actually did it. I created my custom theme (this blue header is my custom theme) and now I try to add it to the amsul pickadate. The problem is I have completely no idea how I can do it other way then by using jquery ".prepend"

Comment: I'd fork the library. Look at this line:

Comment: I'd fork the library. They don't have an easy way to do this using the API as far as I can tell. Look at this line:
https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/master/lib/picker.date.js#L1156
It looks like that's where they're creating the elements. You could look to add in your custom html there.

...or you could do a disgusting hack and attach click handlers to all the child elements or something. But don't do that.